# mail notifications for failed scheduled procedures - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of stored procedures that are scheduled to run at night because execution times are too long to execute them intraday. Usually that works fine.

However, I (and sometimes others) regularly need to adjust lines. As the whole procedure has well over 1000 lines it has happened that people unintentionally made small syntax errors (forgetting an alias for example).

Is there a way to trigger some kind of error notification (preferably by mail) in case the procedure is not executed completely? I've done some research but could not find anything - so I guess its not possible. Or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

> DECLARE ... HANDLER

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html Statement to detect sql errors and then Insert into a table or update an entry

Sending email could be eventually done by user defined functions http://www.mysqludf.org/about.html

But it is not recommended to add functions like email to your database

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer! Why is it not recommended?

Comment: sending emails will cost some server time, second new dlls could provide errors, that will make it difficult to debug. A simple application in dot net or  other programming language that checks the table for new entry and send an email or a sms or do whatever you need, is a better way, besides did you read the mysql manual for that.

Comment: Ok, easiest will probably be to create an error table just as you suggested and then pull that into a gdoc every hour or so. From a gdoc its trivial to have those mails sent based on conditions. The `declare ... handler` part solves my problem. Thanks again!